# How to find minimum and maximum values from user input without functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code**

```
sum = 0
negCount = 0
evenCount = 0
ynResponse = 'y'

while ynResponse == 'y' or ynResponse == 'Y':
    val = float(input('Please enter a value to be processed: '))
    count = count + 1
    sum = sum + val
    if val < 0:
        negCount = negCount + 1
    if val % 2 == 0:
        evenCount = evenCount + 1
    ynResponse = input('Do you have another value to be processed?: ')

print('The number of values entered: ', count)
print('The sum of values entered: ', sum)
print('The average of values entered: ', sum/count)
print('The smallest value entered: ', min)
print('The largest value entered: ', max)
print('The number of negative values: ', negCount)
print('The number of even values: ', evenCount)
```

**Output should look like this**

Enter a value to be processed: 10.4

Do you have another value to be processed? (y/n): y

Enter a value to be processed: -41.2

Do you have another value to be processed? (y/n): y

Enter a value to be processed: 0

Do you have another value to be processed? (y/n): y

Enter a value to be processed: 7.0

Do you have another value to be processed? (y/n): y

Enter a value to be processed: 55.5

Do you have another value to be processed? (y/n): y

Enter a value to be processed: 14

Do you have another value to be processed? (y/n): y

Enter a value to be processed: -4

Do you have another value to be processed? (y/n): n

The number of input values: 7

The sum of the input values: 41.699999999999996

The average of the input values entered: 5.957142857142856

The largest value entered: 55.5

The smallest value entered: -41.2

The number of negative values: 2

The number of even numbers: 3

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 variables, max_ and min_, which start with a value of 0. (Don't use max and min because those are built-in python functions)

Then, on every input, ask if the number is greater than the max (hence the new max) or lower than the min (new min).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize two variables to keep track of the smallest/biggest inputs:

```
smallest = None
biggest = None
```

Inside your input loop, if `smallest` or `biggest` are equal to `None`, then you know this is the very first input, so assign both `smallest` and `biggest` to the current input value.  Otherwise, if the current input is smaller than `smallest` or bigger than `biggest`, replace that value.

```
    if smallest is None or biggest is None:
        smallest = val
        biggest = val
    elif val < smallest:
        smallest = val
    elif val > biggest:
        biggest = val
```